# how enable emacs bookmark plus autocompletion

Tags: completion, bookmarks

How do I make the `C-x j j` prompt dynamically autocomplete?
So when I try "qu" emacs autosuggest "query.rb" from my bookmarks
, without me having to press tab.

Dynamic autocompletion works when I do `C-c p f` (projectile find file),
so I'm thinking Bookmark+ can be made to behave like that.

sidenote
I don't mind installing new packages - just hope they don't conflict with my current set `(ivy projectile magit bookmark+ yasnippet robe expand-region counsel)`.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping to a bookmark with [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) is like doing the same with vanilla Emacs.

Completion of a bookmark name uses standard Emacs function `completing-read` to read the name.  This means that you either have to use a key (e.g. `TAB`) to initiate completion, or you have to use some completion library that lets you make `completing-read` initiate completion automatically.

As far as I know (but I could be wrong about this), [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) is the only completion library that offers this for `completing-read`.

Other completion libraries typically require the use of some alternative, library-specific completion function.  I don't think they can change the behavior of `completing-read` itself.  (Someone can perhaps correct me on this if, say, Helm or Ivy can make existing code that uses `completing-read` behave as you request.)

If you use Icicles then you can have it start completion automatically when you start typing the bookmark name at the `C-j j` prompt.  To get that auto-completion behavior you need to customize option `icicle-incremental-completion` to have value `always` (or any other non-`t`, non-`nil` value).

If you want completion behavior that is even more eager than that -- it shows all possible completions (e.g. all bookmark names) even before you start typing at the prompt -- then also set option `icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag` to non-`nil`.

Option `icicle-incremental-completion-delay` is
the number of seconds to wait before updating `*Completions*`
incrementally.  It has an effect only when the number of
completion candidates is greater than the value of option
`icicle-incremental-completion-threshold`.

[This doc](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion#IncrementalCompletion) explains more about this.

---

In addition, Icicles has specific [support for Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Bookmark_Enhancements). For example, in Icicle mode, commands such as `C-x j j` for jumping to a bookmark let you complete against any combination of the *bookmark* name, the target *file or buffer* name, and any *tags* the bookmark might have.  (For that you need to set option `icicle-show-multi-completion-flag` to non-`nil`.)

---

What's often called *"autocompletion"* in Emacs is available with several libraries.  [`auto-complete-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) is one example; [`company-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode) is another. But it typically refers to completing buffer text as you type it, not to completion of input you type into the minibuffer. (Icicles is generally about the latter: minibuffer completion.)